# Automatically open an Android app without tapping icon

Tags: android

Can you realize an Android application that works in the background so that it opens to the occurrence of a certain event without tapping the application icon?

Comment: Depends, what kind of event?

Comment: External Apps can open your App using an Intent. You can register for Broadcasts so that your App loads upon a specific event. It all depends on what it is you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: You can use Broadcast to do this, eg. to listen when the phone power on.

Comment: Please add more detail to your question, otherwise it's hard to understand what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

We can launch an app using broadcast receiver and defining the intent action:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
 /** This class is used to register the broadcast receiver 
  * as soon as device boot completes this broadcast receiver functionality comes into function and you can launch your application */
public class HomeScreenLaunch extends BroadcastReceiver {

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)){
        Intent launch = new Intent(context, ActivityName.class);
        launch.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(launch);
    }   
 }
```

}

Here is the code to define this broadcast receiver in manifest file:

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.xyz.HomeScreenLaunch"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

> In the OnCreate method of activity you want to launch from via event listener you need to add the following code. This will wake up the device and will unlock it automatically to launch itself.

```
 KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock lock = ((KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE)).newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        PowerManager powerManager = ((PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE));
        PowerManager.WakeLock wake = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "TAG");

        lock.disableKeyguard();
        wake.acquire();

        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_accept_reject);
```

> For listening the event Broadcast Receivers are used. These are having two types: 1)statically registered (Needs manifest permission) 
>   2) dynamically registered (manifest permission is not needed)
>   For first type you can refer to the answer of Mr. Rohit Sharma.
>   For 2nd type I am attaching the following code.

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;


public class SmsService extends Service {

    private String Sender=null;
    private String Code=null;
    public void setCode(String code){
        Code=code;
    }
    public void setSender(String sender){
        Sender=sender;
    }
    private IBinder mBinder = new MyBinder();
    private BroadcastReceiver smsReceiver;

    private static final String ACTION="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        smsReceiver=new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // Do whatever you need it to do when it receives the broadcast
                // Example show a Toast message...
                Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
                Log.i("Receiver","broadcast received");

                if (extras == null)
                    return;

                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) extras.get("pdus");
                SmsMessage msg = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0]);
                String origNumber = msg.getOriginatingAddress();
                String msgBody = msg.getMessageBody();
                Log.i("Receiver",origNumber);
                Log.i("Receiver",msgBody);
                Log.i("Receiver", intent.toString());

                if(Sender!=null && origNumber.contains(Sender)){
                    if(Code!=null && msgBody.contains(Code)){
                        Log.i("Receiver","matched");
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        final IntentFilter theFilter = new IntentFilter();
        theFilter.addAction(ACTION);
        theFilter.setPriority(2147483647);
        this.registerReceiver(this.smsReceiver, theFilter);
        Log.i("Received","service");
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        return mBinder;
    }

    public class MyBinder extends Binder {
        public SmsService getService() {
            return SmsService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(smsReceiver);

    }
}
```